# How to create an array of selected options using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a basic feature that allows the users to create an array of openning hours for their business.

I have everything set up and got it working up to a certain level.

```js
 var hours[];
 $(document).on('change','.smallSelect', function()
 {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var day = $(this).attr('data-day');
  var when = $(this).attr('data-when');

  hours = $.grep(hours, function(item) { 
   return item.day !== day;
  });

  if(when == 'from')
  {
   var to = $('.smallSelect[data-day="'+day+'"]:not(:first)').val();
   var newhour = {
"day": ""+day+"",
"from": ""+val+"",
"to": ""+to+""
   };
  }

  if(when == 'to')
  {
   var fr = $('.smallSelect[data-day="'+day+'"]').val();
   var newhour = {
 "day": ""+day+"",
 "from": ""+fr+"",
 "to": ""+val+""
};
  }

  hours.push(newhour);
  console.log(hours);
 });
```

```css
.hours {
width:100%;
}

.day, .from, .to {
   width:30%;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hours" id="">
 <div class="day">Day</div>
 <div class="from">From</div>
 <div class="to">To</div>
</div>

<div class="hours" id="">
 <div class="day">Monday</div>
 <div class="from">
  <select class="smallSelect" data-day="Monday" data-when="from">
  <option value="CLOSED">Select</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
  <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01.00 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01.30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02.00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02.30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03.00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03.30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04.00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04.30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05.00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05.30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06.00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06.30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07.00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07.30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08.00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08.30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09.00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09.30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10.00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10.30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11.00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11.30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12.00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12.30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01.00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01.30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02.00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02.30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03.00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03.30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04.00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04.30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">05.00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">05.30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">06.00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">06.30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">07.00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">07.30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">08.00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">08.30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">09.00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">09.30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10.00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10.30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11.00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11.30 PM</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="to">
  <select class="smallSelect" data-day="Monday" data-when="to">
  <option value="CLOSED">Select</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
  <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01.00 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01.30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02.00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02.30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03.00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03.30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04.00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04.30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05.00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05.30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06.00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06.30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07.00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07.30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08.00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08.30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09.00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09.30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10.00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10.30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11.00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11.30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12.00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12.30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01.00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01.30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02.00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02.30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03.00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03.30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04.00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04.30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">05.00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">05.30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">06.00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">06.30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">07.00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">07.30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">08.00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">08.30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">09.00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">09.30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10.00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10.30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11.00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11.30 PM</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="hours" id="">
 <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
 <div class="from">
  <select class="smallSelect" data-day="Tuesday" data-when="from">
  <option value="CLOSED">Select</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
  <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01.00 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01.30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02.00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02.30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03.00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03.30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04.00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04.30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05.00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05.30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06.00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06.30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07.00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07.30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08.00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08.30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09.00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09.30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10.00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10.30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11.00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11.30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12.00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12.30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01.00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01.30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02.00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02.30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03.00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03.30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04.00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04.30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">05.00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">05.30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">06.00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">06.30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">07.00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">07.30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">08.00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">08.30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">09.00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">09.30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10.00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10.30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11.00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11.30 PM</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="to">
  <select class="smallSelect" data-day="Tuesday" data-when="to">
  <option value="CLOSED">Select</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
  <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01.00 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01.30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02.00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02.30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03.00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03.30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04.00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04.30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05.00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05.30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06.00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06.30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07.00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07.30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08.00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08.30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09.00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09.30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10.00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10.30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11.00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11.30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12.00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12.30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01.00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01.30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02.00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02.30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03.00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03.30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04.00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04.30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">05.00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">05.30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">06.00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">06.30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">07.00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">07.30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">08.00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">08.30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">09.00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">09.30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10.00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10.30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11.00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11.30 PM</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

If you select `from` and `to`, this will be added to an array for that particular day.

However, everytime I select a `from` or `to`, the current value of the other select option is being ignored!

**Example:** under Monday, select a `*from*` time of 12:30 and select a 02:30 for the `*to*` time. Now, if you look at the final array in the console you will see something like this:

```
day: "Monday"
from: "CLOSED"
to: "02:30"
```

But the result should be:

```
day: "Monday"
from: "12:30"
to: "02:30"
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: _But the result should be:_ I see no error in that. Response is already what you've mentioned

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, the results should be from the value of selected options. but its not.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie - Please actually **read** the [MCVE](/help/mcve) link above. Note the "minimal" part.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie I reformated your code. According version control 1539 characters has being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this  `var hours = [];`

instead of

`var hours[];`

it will work for you.

you can also refer JSFiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/qeh7dupr/1/

Comment: sorry that was my typo. I already use that in my code. but still not working.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie please check JSfiddle link which i add in my answer .